# Post a big image on my wall with javascript api

Tags: facebook

I tried to post an image on my wall from my application. I want the image will be seen its original size and not like a small picture.

I have tried two ways to do it and it does not work.

```
FB.ui(
    {
    target_id:'ID',
    method: 'stream.publish',
    access_token:accessToken,
    attachment: {
        name: 'test name',
        caption: 'Caption here.',
        description: 'description here',
        href: 'http://facebook.com/mysite',
        media: [{'type': 'image', 'src': pic,  width: '150', height: '120', 'href': 'MY_SITE'}]
        },
    message: '',
    },
    function(response) {
        if (response && response.post_id) {
            alert('Post was published.');
        } else {
           console.log(response);
           alert('Post was not published.');
        }
    }
);
```

This posts the image on my wall, but it's a small picture. I tried to post the image to my album like this:

```
FB.api('me/photos', 'post',
    { 
    url:'MY_URL',
    href:'MY_LINK,
    message: 'photo description',                
    access_token:accessToken
    },
    function(response) {
        console.log(response);
        if (!response || response.error) {
            alert('Error occurred');
        } else {
            alert('Post ID: ' + response.id);
        }
});
```

But the image was not displayed on my wall. It's in my album but I need to click on "approve photos". Just after clicking, it displays on my wall.

My question is: if I use the first code, is there a way that the image will display in its original size?

And if I use the second code, how do I make it automatically publish on my wall from my album?

Comment: more better to use "facebook graph API".

Answer (score 1):

Doing a post to 'me/photos' will create a new album for your app and post a photo there. You could consider creating a new album or uploading to an existing album, and letting Facebook handle the size of the photo as it appears to friends in news feed. Take a look at this blog post describing what you need. It's a `php` example, but the API calls are the same in `JavaScript` https://developers.facebook.com/blog/post/498/

Comment: But this code not post the photo on my wall, its just upload to myAlbum.

Comment: Adding a photo will cause the story to show up on your friends' news feeds. Is that the desired behaviour?

Comment: But its not, because this code just upload to my album, and this photo wait i approve it, after i approve this photo its wiil show on my wall.

Answer (score 1):

i don't know what i did, but this code work for me:

```
FB.api('me/photos', 'post', { 
                url:pic.toString().replace('.png', '.fb.png'),                    
                message:message,
                access_token:accessToken
                }, function(response) {                    
                  }
            });
```

i add `scope: 'email,user_photos,publish_stream`
to my code and this add picture to the user's album and immediately show on the user wall.

Answer (score 0):

In the first example you provided I see `width` and `height`. Increasing those values, does not help ?

For example:

```
// ...
media: [{'type': 'image', 'src': pic,  width: '1024', height: '768', 'href': 'MY_SITE'}]
// ...
```